# Compare user input with server data

Tags: android

I developed an app and now I need a method that compares the password and email input from the user with my SQL database. But actually I have no idea how to write that. Can anyone help me or give me a link to any website? becaus I didn't find anything

Comment: Dont require Java tag. Misleading to Java answer providers

Comment: Maybe Google "how to connect to sql server with Android". I doubt very many people will be happy just writing code for you without some attempt on your part.

Comment: hey follow this link to find [how to access sql database from server in android app](https://amitku.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-connect-and-access-sql-database-server-from-android-app/)